# Background cuts

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, quantum-chromodynamics

I am considering background events like, $p p \rightarrow t \bar{t}$ and QCD events where t is a top quark. I want also to reduced the QCD events such that QCD events will be less observed than that of
$p p \rightarrow t \bar{t}$. Is it okay technically, to apply different sets of cuts to different background process? Or can anyone give me some hints to reduce QCD events?

Comment: please clarify what   t is in your expression $p p \rightarrow t t~$ . As it is written the expression does not conserve anything. Also what do you mean by QCD events?

Comment: Sorry it should be $pp \rightarrow t\bar{t}$ where t is a top quark.

Comment: It still is an expression that does not conserve baryon number of charge or ... you should ad an X there for the rest of the particles created in the interaction. The top has QCD interactions.

Comment: Its  two proton collision, then $t \bar{t}$ is produce in it. I think it should be $p \bar{p} \rightarrow t \bar{t}$. The gauge boson, i considering is all posible gauge boson in the process, $Z^0$, $\gamma$ and etc.

Comment: look at this https://ccwww.kek.jp/pdg/cpep/top_pro.html . Also I found this theses  on the subject https://digital.library.unt.edu/ark:/67531/metadc1408917/m2/1/high_res_d/15017276.pdf

Comment: Thank you for the references.